# Problema React Carrito de Compras no agrega mas de un item solo lo suma

Tags: reactjs

estoy un poco desesperado, por eso recurro a ustedes, es mi primer proyecto de react, actualmente tengo un problema con mi carrito :

- Al darle click al boton de add product se agrega al carrito como se ve :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero el problema que si quiero agregar otro producto no agrega uno nuevo, sino que lo suma :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

### **Mi codigo es este, el contexto (CartContext.jsx) :**

```
 import { createContext, useState } from "react";
import React from "react";

export const Cartcontext = createContext();

export function CartProvider({ children }) {
  const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);

  const addToCart = (item) => {
    const productInCartindex = cart.find((product) => product.id === item.id);

    console.log(item);

    if (productInCartindex) {
      productInCartindex.quantity += 1;
      setCart([...cart]);
    } else {
      setCart((prevState) => [...prevState, { ...item, quantity: 1 }]);
    }
  };

  const clearCart = () => {
    setCart([]);
  };
  return (
    <Cartcontext.Provider value={{ cart, addToCart, clearCart }}>
      {children}
    </Cartcontext.Provider>
  );
}
```

---

### **Luego el Widget (CartWidgetSh) donde aparece los productos y que consume el contexto es este :**

```
 import React from "react";
import cartshop from "../../Assets//shoppingcart.png";
import { useId } from "react";
import "./style.css";
import { useCart } from "../CustomHook-comp/useCart";
import { useContext } from "react";
import { Cartcontext } from "../../context/CartContext";

function CartItem({
  title,
  brand,
  price,
  image,
  quantity,
  prod,
  addToCart,
  clearCart,
}) {
  return (
    <li>
      <img className="customprodimg" src={image} alt={title} />
      <div>
        <strong>Tabla</strong> - ${price}
      </div>

      <footer>
        <small>Qty: {quantity}</small>
        <button onClick={addToCart}>+</button>
      </footer>
    </li>
  );
}

export default function CartWidgetSh() {
  const cartCheckboxId = useId();
  const { cart, clearCart, addToCart } = useContext(Cartcontext);

  return (
    <>
      <label className="cart-button" htmlFor={cartCheckboxId}>
        <img className="customcartimage" src={cartshop} />
      </label>
      <input id={cartCheckboxId} type="checkbox" hidden />

      <aside className="cart">
        <ul>
          {cart.map((product) => (
            <CartItem
              key={product.id}
              addToCart={() => addToCart(product)}
              {...product}
            />
          ))}

          <button onClick={clearCart}>Clear</button>
        </ul>
      </aside>
    </>
  );
}
```

---

Muchachos les agradezco toda la ayuda, de verdad que quizas me compliqué mas de la cuenta, pero no logro resolver este tema, gracias a todos de antemano!

si quieren verlo en vivo el error lo subi a este host

http://ecommerceprojectsnowboardrea.infinityfreeapp.com

Comment: ¿De casualidad no tendrán el mismo ID? Podrías imprimir `productInCartindex` también para ver qué sucede.

Comment: gracias ya he resulto el tema, esto fue lo que corregi :    const addToCart = (item) => {
    {
      const isInArray = cart.indexOf(item) !== -1;

      console.log(item);

      if (isInArray) {
        const productInCartindex = cart.filter(
          (product) => product.title === item.title
        );
        productInCartindex[0].quantity += 1;
        setCart([...cart]);
      } else {
        setCart((prevState) => [...prevState, { ...item, quantity: 1 }]);
      }
    }
  };